# How to gain access to the controls of other pages in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I created a UserControl I post a ListView as DataTemplate

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <local:Favorites/>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

UserControl I need to use the Text property of a TextBlock on the page of the ListView. How do I us access to that and other controls?

Example:

```
if (query.Count == 0)
{
    NoPreferiti.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  //NO ACCESS
}
```

Comment: You can't. Either try with Element property or pass it as a property of Favorites. For example if Favorites has "Text" put it <local:Favorites Text="{Binding Text}"/>

Answer (score 0):

The only way that is possible is if you pass the "parent" controls to the UserControl as properties, either through code behind or through xaml.

An easy way can be adding a Loaded event to the UserControl in the parent page and in the event handler you assign the controls you want to change inside the UserControl as parameters of the UserControl.